# Intransitive urns

Tags: mathematics, probability

N balls with numbers 1,2,3...N are filled arbitrarily into 3 urns A,B and C - but no urn may remain empty. We write P(A,B) for the probability that a ball chosen randomly from urn A shows a higher number than a ball chosen randomly from urn B.
We call the tree urns intransitive if P(A,B)>1/2, P(B,C)>1/2 and P(C,A)>1/2.

1. Give the smallest possible N and the corresponding contents of the urns such that the three urns are intransitive.
2. Give the smallest possible N and the corresponding contents of the urns such that additionally P(A,B)=P(B,C)=P(C,A).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 

> N=7 (1,5,6,),(4),(2,3,7)

2. 

> N=9 (2,6,7),(1,5,9),(3,4,8) P=5/9

or

> (1,6,8),(3,5,7),(2,4,9)

Comment: Correct! Is there an easy argument to see that the solution for question 1 is unique? I have none. Question 2 has 2 solutions btw.

Comment: Nope, I have nothing elegant.